# IOS touch joystick controller for a 3D game that is third person in Unity 3D

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I need help creating a joystick that I can move left, right, up, and down to move my player/cube to the in the direction the joystick is in, and the cube has to keep moving if the joystick is in that position.  If they joystick is not touched I need to not move the play/cube.  It would be very helpful because it is the last step I need to do to publish my game, thanks!  My game is created in Unity 3D

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Codes maybe ? Please edit your question to post your codes.

Comment: I erased all the code I tried for joystick cause I was starting to get mad with it.  I need someone to tell me how to code in a joystick that is at the bottom right.